# elixir - error loading module ranch_server - recompile this module with an 20 compiler

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, beam

I'm trying to run an existing elixir project that works on my other computer, on a new computer (both are mac).

When I run iex -S mix I get:

```
iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]


11:47:52.651 [error] Loading of /Users/benjamin/vepo/api/_build/dev/lib/ranch/ebin/ranch_server.beam failed: :badfile


11:47:52.651 [error] beam/beam_load.c(1863): Error loading module ranch_server:
  This BEAM file was compiled for a later version of the run-time system than 20.
  To fix this, please recompile this module with an 20 compiler.
  (Use of opcode 164; this emulator supports only up to 159.)



11:47:52.657 [info]  Application ranch exited: :ranch_app.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: :ranch_server
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :ranch_server.start_link/0 is undefined (module :ranch_server is not available)
            (ranch) :ranch_server.start_link()
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:365: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:348: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:314: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:365: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:333: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
** (Mix) Could not start application ranch: :ranch_app.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: :ranch_server
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :ranch_server.start_link/0 is undefined (module :ranch_server is not available)
            (ranch) :ranch_server.start_link()
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:365: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:348: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:314: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:365: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:333: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:api benjamin$
```

I think I need to recompile `ranch_server.beam`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need to install Erlang 21.0 or later. You're currently running version 20. What is the version on the machine that works?

[ASDF](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang) is useful for managing multiple versions of erlang on the same machine.

Or if you just want to recompile the dependency, you could try

```
mix do deps.clean ranch_server, deps.get, deps.compile
```

Comment: Thank you. Erlang 20 was the correct version. I did `mix deps.clean --all` and then `mix deps.get` to fix it which essentially worked for the same reason as the bottom of your answer.